# Sendmail with CSV file & plain body text

Tags: shell-script, sendmail

I am trying to send an email with `CSV file` as attachment and also print the data available in the text file as `Email body` using the below shell scripts. But im getting only attachment and there is no Email body available in the email which I have got after the execution of the below scripts , can someone help to resolve the issue.

**Script Execution:**

```
sh <script_name> CSV File 2012
```

**Code - 1 :**

```
#!/bin/bash
export MAILTO="abc@hello.com"
export SUBJECT="Test - \"$1\""
export BODY="$2.txt"
export ATTACH_CSV=""$2"_"$3".csv"
csv_file=$( basename "$ATTACH_CSV" )
{
echo "To: $MAILTO"
echo "Subject: $SUBJECT"
echo "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"FILEBOUNDARY\""
echo "--FILEBOUNDARY"
echo "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"MSGBOUNDARY\""
echo "--MSGBOUNDARY"
echo "Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"
echo "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit"
#echo "Content-Disposition: inline"
cat "$BODY"
echo "--MSGBOUNDARY--"
echo "--FILEBOUNDARY"
echo "Content-Type: text/csv"
echo "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"${csv_file}\""
echo "Content-Transfer-Encoding: uuencode"
uuencode "$ATTACH_CSV" "$csv_file"
echo "--FILEBOUNDARY--"
} | sendmail -t
```

**Code - 2 :**

```
#!/bin/bash
export MAILTO="abc@hello.com"
export SUBJECT="Test - \"$1\""
export BODY="$2.txt"
export ATTACH_CSV=""$2"_"$3".csv"
csv_file=$( basename "$ATTACH_CSV" )
{
        echo "To: $MAILTO"
        echo "Subject: $SUBJECT"
        echo "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"FILEBOUNDARY\""

        echo "--FILEBOUNDARY"
        echo "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"MSGBOUNDARY\""

        echo "--MSGBOUNDARY"
        echo "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1"
        echo "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit"
        echo "Content-Disposition: inline"
        cat "$BODY"
        echo "--MSGBOUNDARY--"

        echo "--FILEBOUNDARY"
        echo "Content-Type: text/csv"
        echo "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"${csv_file}\""
        echo "Content-Transfer-Encoding: uuencode"
        uuencode "$ATTACH_CSV" "$csv_file"
        echo "--FILEBOUNDARY--"
} | /usr/sbin/sendmail -t
```

Comment: So the content of the mail is in `File.txt`?

Comment: Yes you are right

Answer (score 1):

- You're constructing an invalid message. You always need an empty line between message header and body. In your header, you have two occurrences of `Content-Type:` with different boundary definitions, and the boundary strings between them which only belong in the body to separate MIME parts. I suggest you look up some in-depth information or tutorial on how MIME messages must be structured.
- When you represent essentially the same information once as text and once as a CSV file, it's probably better to use `multipart/alternative` to denote that these two MIME parts present the same information in different formats, but this may depend on the recipient's user agent, so your mileage may vary.

Comment: I have updated the another version of the script which i have used. As you specified above i have tried using the ```multipart/alternative``` also but the issue is still the same.

Comment: You have placed empty lines between the echo commands, but you did not add echo commands to emit empty lines. I suggest instead of piping to sendmail you first store into a file and manually check whether it looks like a valid mail message.

Comment: I have tried it and it looks like valid mail message only, but still not working. Can you correct the script and let me know

Comment: I'm sorry I don't have the time and inclination to do that now. You might add the output of your script to your question so people can give recommendations without needing to run your script.

Comment: Output is the same as i told earlier, im getting only CSV file attachment and there is no Email body appearing in the mail

Comment: Apparently you didn't read what I wrote. Your script does not generate empty lines, but they are needed to create a well-formed mail message.